# Flutter different screen navigation using on onTap uncertain ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i navigate to a different route in ListView `querySnapshot.docs[index].data()['image']`. In my case all the cards will navigate to different route.
Relevant code with facing this issue:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/screens/location_list_screen.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/widgets/nav_drawer.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SelectedCategoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  SelectedCategoryScreen();
  @override
  _SelectedCategoryScreen createState() => _SelectedCategoryScreen();
}

class _SelectedCategoryScreen extends State<SelectedCategoryScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  final Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("movies")
      .orderBy('year', descending: true);

  void gotoPage(String pageName) {
    switch (pageName) {
      case 'home':
        {
          // statements;
          Navigator.push(
              context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (redContext) => HomePage()));
        }
        break;

      case 'yard':
        {
          //statements;
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (redContext) => LocationListScreen()));
        }
        break;

      default:
        {
          throw new Exception("Path ${pageName} not supported");
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  /// Page Controller

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_sharp),
        ),
        title: Container(
          width: 170,
          child: Image.network(
            'https://i.hizliresim.com/sf4asddsau.jpg',
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_queue_outlined),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: NavDrawer(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: query.snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Icon(Icons.error),
                );
              }
              final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot =
                  snapshot.data;
              return ListView(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 28.8, bottom: 16.8),
                    height: 724.8,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: querySnapshot.size,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.8, right: 12),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 214.8,
                          width: 188.4,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.8, bottom: 50),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.6),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                  querySnapshot.docs[index].data()['image'],
                                  maxHeight: 200,
                                  maxWidth: 200),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Stack(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () => gotoPage(querySnapshot
                                          .docs[index]
                                          .data()['page']));

                                  /*  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      CupertinoPageRoute(
                                          builder: (redContext) => MyApp()));*/
                                },
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                bottom: 19.2,
                                left: 19.2,
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.8),
                                  child: BackdropFilter(
                                    filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                                        sigmaY: 19.2, sigmaX: 19.2),
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 26,
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
                                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 9.52,
                                          ),
                                          SvgPicture.asset(
                                              'assets/svg/icon_location.svg'),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 9.52,
                                          ),
                                          SvgPicture.asset(
                                            'assets/svg/icon_location.svg',
                                            height: 50,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 9.52,
                                          ),
                                          SvgPicture.asset(
                                              'assets/svg/icon_location.svg'),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 9.52,
                                          ),
                                          /*  Text(
                                    recommendations[index].name,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 16.8),
                                  ) */
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(70),
                                  child: Text(
                                    querySnapshot.docs[index].data()['title'],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 27,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Firestore:
[image]
If you look at the picture you can easily understand what I mean.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how your document from QuerySnapshot looks like but you could add a field/property that contains the name of the page to be navigated to. Then add a function with a switch-case or if-else statements that control which page to navigate to in your onTap().

```
void gotoPage(String pageName){
   switch(pageName) { 
      case 'home': { 
         // statements; 
   Navigator.push(context,CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (redContext) => HomePage())); 
      } 
      break; 
     
      case 'yard': { 
         //statements; 
   Navigator.push(context,CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (redContext) => YardPage()));
      } 
      break; 
         
      default: { 
         throw new Exception(`Path ${pageName} not supported`);
   
      }
      break; 
     }
  }
```

then call it in  onTap.

```
 GestureDetector(onTap: () => gotoPage(querySnapshot.docs[index].data()['page'])  ),
```

where page will be the field/property with the pageName that you would have added to your document

Comment: I am trying this, seems reasonable.

Comment: Ok good luck and dont forget to upvote and mark as answer if it works

Comment: I could not understand where should i place the Switch Case. I am adding the code of the whole page. Can you show me exactly where I should place it?

Comment: ok cool I have updated the answer so the switch case is in a function/ method called gotoPage(). So you  put the function gotoPage() anywhere on your class ```_SelectedCategoryScreen``` as long as its not inside another function such as ```build(...){...}```. So for example you can add it below the ```build(...){...} ``` method/function or above it depending on your style of programming

Comment: Thanks for helping me but i did what you said and i have no error. But i can't tap that. Before i was tapping and i went same page all the time. Now i can't tap.

Comment: Firestore image added, i don't know where is the problem, because i can get images and titles from firestore but i can't navigate another page with similar method.

Comment: did you add the ```page``` field to your firestore document if you didn't you can just use the title instead but be wary of the cases

Comment: Hey Kthree, i uploaded my new firestore image, can you check and say me what is wrong...

Comment: Finally i made it, thanks to everybody.